# Multiple Hidden Imports in Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I know how to use the hidden import function in pyinstaller to import one python library. What if I have multiple python libraries like pyautogui and pandas? How do I hidden import them both?
I’m thinking it looks something like this:

```
pyinstaller Pythonmain.py —hidden-import=‘pyautogui, pandas’
```

I’m sure it’s simple but I can’t find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can repeat the `--hidden-import` option:

```perl
pyinstaller main.py -—hidden-import pandas --hidden-import pyautogui
```

From the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search), emphasis mine:

> --hidden-import MODULENAME
> Name an import not visible in the code of the script(s). **This option can be used
> multiple times**.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll test it soon, it should work!

Comment: Is there a way to specify files through regex for example? As to not repeat a lot of imports

Comment: @Barbaldo you mean the module names right? then, no afaik.

Comment: According to this https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4588 you could maybe write some code to collect all imports but it's not really simple, best I could find.

Comment: thanks @Barbaldo. perhaps some command line manipulation could help here, i'll try to attempt that